# jQuery sortable changing name attribute not showing input name when posted back to php

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, laravel

Hi Im using Laravel and Jquery to create a project which can have many statuses assigned to the tasks from a list of many. The statuses need to be written to the `assigned_statuses` table which has a `project_id` and a `status_id` to form the relevant relationships.

To assign these I have two connected sortable lists which have two hidden inputs, I am using sortable as the tasks in the project will move in a certain order that is assigned when posted back. Anyway my rendered blade file outputs the hidden form with the name of `statuses` and it posts them all back. However I need to know which ones are the assigned ones. This is my code so far:

```
<div class="statuses">
  <div class="statussortableWrapper">
    <ul id="available-statuses" name="available-statuses" class="connected-sortable">
      @foreach($statuses as $status)
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="{{$status->id}}" name="{{$status->id}}">
         {{Form::hidden('available-statuses[]',$status->id,array('class' => 'sortable-hidden-input'))}}
          <span class="label label-primary">{{$status->name}}</span>
         </li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="statussortableWrapper">
     <ul id="assigned-stauses" name="assigned-stauses" class="connected-sortable">    
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>


$(function() {
$( "#available-statuses, #assigned-stauses" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
           var present = $(ui.item).find('.sortable-hidden-input').attr("name", "assigned-statuses[]");
            console.log(present);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

The name attribute is changed on the input which has the class of `.sortable-hidden-input` however when this is posted back it doesn't have the key name in the array, the array is below:

```
array(7) {
    ["project_name"] ""
    ["start_date"] "01/01/2015"
    ["end_date"] "13/03/2015"
    ["available-statuses"] array(2) {
        [0] "17"
        [1] "20"
    }
    array(3) {
        [0] "19"
        [1] "16"
        [2] "18"
    }
}
```

As you can see the available statuses are in its own array but the other assigned statuses id's are not. I'm not sure why as the code successfully assigns the new name attribute on the input. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can successfully capture this on the back end??

### Edit

Statuses Dump:

```
array(5) {
[0] array(8) {
["id"] "16"
["name"] "Backlog"
["order"] "0"
["created_at"] "2015-07-19 17:41:25"
["updated_at"] "2015-07-19 20:29:20"
}
[1] array(8) {
["id"] "17"
["name"] "Open"
["order"] "4"
["created_at"] "2015-07-19 17:41:25"
["updated_at"] "2015-07-19 20:29:11"
}
[2] array(8) {
["id"] "18"
["name"] "In Progress"
["order"] "1"
["created_at"] "2015-07-19 17:41:25"
["updated_at"] "2015-07-19 20:29:11"
}
[3] array(8) {
["id"] "19"
["name"] "Review"
["order"] "2"
["created_at"] "2015-07-19 17:41:25"
["updated_at"] "2015-07-19 20:29:21"
}
[4] array(8) {
["id"] "20"
["name"] "Done"
["order"] "3"
["created_at"] "2015-07-19 17:41:25"
["updated_at"] "2015-07-19 20:30:14"
}
}
```

Full Form

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="create-project-layout">
    <div class="page-intro">
        <h3>Create new Project</h3>
        <span>* required fields</span>
    </div>
    <div class="all-project">
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => route('project.add'), 'class'=> 'create-project-form')) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form:: label ('project_name', 'Project name *' )}}
            {{ Form:: text ('project_name', '', array('placeholder' => 'Project Two', 'class' =>'form-control', 'id' => 'project-name') )}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form:: label ('start_date', 'Start Date *' )}}
            <div class='input-group date'>
            {{ Form:: text ('start_date', '', array('placeholder' => '2015/08/31', 'class' =>'form-control', 'data-provide' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd', 'id' => 'start_date') )}}
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <div class="">
            {{ Form:: label ('end_date', 'End Date *' )}}
            <div class='input-group date'>
            {{ Form:: text ('end_date', '', array('placeholder' => '2015/08/31', 'class' =>'form-control', 'data-provide' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd', 'id' => 'end_date') )}}
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('globalstatues', 'These statuses have been assigned globally to all projects.')}}
            @foreach($globalstatuses as $status)
               <span class="label label-primary">{{$status->name}}</span>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {{Form::label('overideglobalstatues', 'Would you like to override?')}}
            <div class="override-status">
                <p>The statuses on the left are available for selection. Drag them to the area on the right in the order you would like the scrum board to run. E.g. Backlog > In Progress > Review > Done > Deloyped.</p>
                <div class="statussortableWrapper">
                    <ul id="available-statuses" name="available-statuses" class="connected-sortable">
                        @foreach($statuses as $status)
                        <li class="ui-state-default" id="{{$status->id}}" name="{{$status->id}}">{{Form::hidden('status[]',$status->id,array('class' => 'sortable-hidden-input'))}}<span class="label label-primary">{{$status->name}}</span></li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="statussortableWrapper">
                    <ul id="assigned-stauses" name="assigned-stauses" class="connected-sortable">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Create new project', array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id'=> 'create-project')) }}
        
        {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
@stop
```

Comment: @crush no thats not required as I have a table `statuses` which holds the status `name` so I can build the relationship using the `status_id` in the `assigned_statuses` table

Comment: Could you add your PHP definition of `$statuses`. Need some sample data.

Comment: @crush is a var dump ok? i've updated the question, if not let me know what you need :)

Comment: How does this get posted back to your server? Sure var_dump is fine.

Comment: atm I'm just posting back via php, but I want to do it via a post ajax request

Comment: Do you have a form around the div?

Comment: @crush yes I've posted this to the question also

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the problem. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sahtgq2/1/). I've used knockout to do what you are doing with Laravel. I'm using `jQuery`'s serialize() method to produce what would be sent back to your post back. What I see should result in you having the key name you are looking for of `assigned-statuses`. The only thing I've changed to my knowledge is fixing the simple typo in the name of assigned-statuses. The html rendered by output should be the same as your Laravel output.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding an online environment that I can submit my form to and get a PHP echo back from. If you could setup a `<?php var_dump($_POST);` script that I can hit, that would be great.

Comment: @crush do you have teamviewer?

Comment: I do, but not sure what you're planning haha.

Comment: @crush I can do a var_dump of the post can you can see it?

Comment: @crush not a good idea?

Comment: Can you host a simple PHP file on a publicly accessible server that does `<?php var_dump($_POST);` and give me a URL to it so that I can direct this JSFiddle at it?

Comment: I must go for now. Hopefully someone can help. I don't see why the code isn't working. The jsfiddle produces a result that should work.

Comment: @crush can i see the fiddle?

Comment: I posted it earlier. Here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/5sahtgq2/1/ Take a look at your JavaScript console's output after moving some stuff to the red box, and hitting submit. You'll see the serialized form-url-encoded data that would get sent to your PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, this looks like a formatted array:

```
  array(7) {
    ["project_name"] ""
    ["start_date"] "01/01/2015"
    ["end_date"] "13/03/2015"
    ["available-statuses"] array(2) {
        [0] "17"
        [1] "20"
    }
    array(3) {
        [0] "19"
        [1] "16"
        [2] "18"
    }
}
```

Right click on your browser and view source and see if the contents are different.

Comment: @user3410846 youre right i have a plugin, it was hiding the name of the array. thanks!